# How to test classes with StreamBridge in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a class which injects StreamBridge to send sometimes some events. Tests which uses this class fails, because no bean exists. I've tried to

> @MockBean StreamBridge streamBridge

it with Mockito, but it fails, because of some static content. Tried to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.cloud.stream.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
</dependency>
```

but didn't help. I've tried also

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
```

but TestChannelBinderConfiguration doesn't exists too.

Any idea how can I make this StreamBridge be available for tests?

Comment: the error is:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Looks like this combination did the trick: 
@ComponentScan({"org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test"})
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these tests to see how `StreamBridge` is tested in the framework:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/core/spring-cloud-stream-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamBridgeTests.java

Comment: I don't want to test StreamBridge. I want to mock it just to satisfy dependency. I saw this example, but it doesn't help. It doesn't autowire, it reads StreamBridge from context, but I don't understand, how it was created in the context.

Comment: Above link is broken

Comment: Updated the link. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The link is broken again.@sobychacko

@Marx Did you find a way to mock StreamBridge?

Comment: Updated the link in the answer. If you update to the `4.0.0` version of Spring Cloud Stream, `StreamBridge` now provides a contract through the interface `StreamOperation` using which you can do better mocking.

Comment: See the Notes at the end of the ref docs section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_channel_interceptors_with_streambridge

Comment: I've made a refactor and extracted StreamBridge call to separate class. Then I mock whole class.